# Why using .Copy After:= a sheet containing a chart causes its data series to change in the resulting sheet's chart?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm using the code below to duplicate a template sheet and give it a couple of characteristics according to the selected cell's content. It works fine up to a point, but since it contains a chart, the resulting sheet's chart is grabbing data from different ranges, than the ones set in the template sheet:

```
Sub AddSheets()
    Dim cell        As Excel.Range
    Dim allShares   As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook
    Dim destTicker  As Range
    Dim startDate   As Range
    Dim endDate     As Range
    Dim sheetName   As String
    Dim sh        'As Sheets
    
    Set allShares = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("all shares")
    Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Selection.Column > 1 Then
                MsgBox "Please make sure you Select at least a ticker in column A"
                Exit Sub
            Else
    For Each cell In Selection
        With wbToAddSheetsTo
                For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                    If Worksheets(i).Name = cell.Value Then
                        MsgBox "This name Is already in use!"
                        Worksheets(cell.Value).Activate
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next
                allShares.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
                ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Value = cell.Value
                ActiveSheet.Range("J4").Formula = "='all shares'!$J$4"
                ActiveSheet.Range("J5").Formula = "='all shares'!$J$5"
                ExtractData
                On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next cell
    wbToAddSheetsTo.Worksheets("List of Stocks").Activate
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm not sure I'm missing something here.

Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't, AFAIK. Are you inserting or removing any rows, columns, or other ranges that might end up changing the location of the chart data?

Comment: Hi, @ChristoferWeber! I'm not. The sheet has a couple of 4 column ranges. The chart in the original/template grabs it from the second range ("R73:R117"), but the resulting sheet is grabbing it from the range ("A72:A117"). So intriguing!

Comment: @ChristoferWeber! Just solved by removing the function ```ExtractData``` I was calling in the for loop.